# loading a CSV file to Bigtable error message:error parsing headers: the first column must be empty for column-family and column name rows

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to load a CSV file to Google Bigtable.
Following the instruction from the documentation, https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference, but still getting this error:

$ cbt import knn-item KNN_Items_movieset.csv
2022/05/09 15:57:27 -creds flag unset, will use gcloud credential
2022/05/09 15:57:29 error parsing headers: the first column must be empty for column-family and column name rows

Here is the first line of CSV file.  As you can see the first field is empty.

$ head KNN_Items_movieset.csv
,NN1,NN2,NN3,NN4,NN5,CORR1,CORR2,CORR3,CORR4,CORR5
1,3114,2355,588,34,1028,0.913666599,0.854363517,0.773018874,0.749784262,0.748810647
2,3802,3123,3887,552,3489,0.80052671,0.748505988,0.731987561,0.730157424,0.726546693
3,3450,252,500,2717,520,0.836778314,0.664503125,0.64360476,0.639778027,0.635892794
4,3534,477,3325,1678,1181,0.676159616,0.672537245,0.649425289,0.63952865,0.630579547
5,539,2424,3705,834,3257,0.779063464,0.771126796,0.752876978,0.723068424,0.721982964
6,1718,507,3169,1174,2231,0.742420472,0.716185759,0.690725103,0.685257331,0.680264075
7,2424,62,539,2724,1890,0.786463102,0.743178729,0.732923908,0.725663973,0.718495613
8,1135,2100,1017,1890,31,0.640046203,0.603959854,0.595405488,0.587100113,0.585704851
9,2249,2463,2456,2490,315,0.725624981,0.674192344,0.654899469,0.645862902,0.640962242

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This happened to me as well. Oddly enough, I just opened the file highlighted all of the contents and then copied and pasted it into a new file. Then executed the import statement with the new file, and somehow that fixed it. Hesitant to make this an answer as i'm not really sure why it worked, but give it a shot and report back.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in a `column-family=YOUR_CF` to the input command otherwise it will thing the CSV has 2 header rows: one for column families and the other for the column qualifiers so the final command would be `cbt import knn-item KNN_Items_movieset.csv column-family=YOUR_CF`

Comment: I just ran the command you have above without making any changes to my CSV file.  Getting the identical error.                                                                    
cbt import knn-item KNN_Items_movieset.csv column-family=YOUR_CF
2022/05/09 17:20:43 -creds flag unset, will use gcloud credential
2022/05/09 17:20:51 error parsing headers: the first column must be empty for column-family and column name rows

Comment: Just checking, did you replace `YOUR_CF` with an existing column family name that is on your table?

Comment: what happens if there are 2 column family?  don't you need 2 headers?  The top header supposed to align the column-family with columns.

Comment: You can have two column families like so

,fam_1,,fam_2,
,col_a,col_b,col_x,col_y
myrow1,a,b,x,y

Comment: -In case there are multiple column families, cbt command is comma separated like this: `cbt import knn-item KNN_Items_movieset.csv column-family=YOUR_CF1, YOUR_CF2`?  I am assuming that I do not have to worry about converting data into byte type. Correct?

Comment: You don't have to worry about converting things to bytes. I believe it just treats everything as a string

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this also but I think your issue is with the column family you created.  Check to make sure you have this for its settings.

check: Version based policy
give it a max version of: 1